# Best Way to Save Highcharts Graph to Webpage?

Tags: javascript, python, highcharts, flask

I have a web app that I'm writing with FLASK and JavaScript which allows the user to drag and drop a CSV file, the CSV file is then parsed and rendered via Highcharts -- all with JavaScript. Trouble is, the chart obviously won't save in the form.

My question is, how would I go about storing the chart that I just rendered? I'm kind of doing reverse logic here instead of feeding the data to highcharts via a db, so maybe that would be a better option?

Comment: Please provide us with a minimal, complete and verifiable example [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In short, what have you tried?

Comment: Do you just want to store the chart image after render or store the chart options + data supplied via CSV?

Comment: There is a plugin for Highcharts that allows data exporting - into CSV format: http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/7/Export%20Data To get chart's options you could call [Chart.getOptions()](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/1aacf2433fb94b1658300616fd442f82b774f9c5/js/parts/Options.js#L401-L407)